# Do different platforms have different double precision in C?

Tags: c

C code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double x = 1.0/3.0;
    printf("%.32f\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

On Windows Server 2008 R2, I compile and run the code using MSVC 2013. The output is:

```
0.33333333333333331000000000000000
```

On macOS High Sierra, I compile and run the same code using Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2). The output is:

```
0.33333333333333331482961625624739
```

Running the same code on [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/QaLAO6) gives the same result as the one on macOS.

I know the double-precision float-point format has only about 15 or 16 significant decimal digits. The number keeps the precise decimal representation of the 64-bit binary value of 1/3 (as the [Wikipedia's explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)) on macOS platform, but why is it "truncated" on Windows platform?

Comment: I just ran your code (MSVC 2017, Windows 10, i7-class CPU) and the output is: `0.33333333333333331482961625624739` What CPU are you running this on? And what are the project properties when you build the code?

Comment: I'm going to say that there's no difference in the number itself. The only difference is the way `printf` displays it. To prove it, try `char *p = &x; for (int i=0;i<8;i++) printf("%02x ", p[i]);`

Comment: Try compiling your code with the GCC flag `-ffloat-store`. I hope this will give the same result on both machines.

Comment: It doesn't makes sense to analyze in-significant decimal digits,- there can be anything with no particular reason and may be also implementation-defined

Comment: Answering your question *Do different platforms have different double precision in C?*: In this case different results are normal on different architecture.

Comment: @YePhIcK The code runs on University's HPC server which has two Intel Xeon E5-2637 v2 CPUs. I compile the code on the command line. Precisely, in Windows' command prompt: `cl foobar.c` after `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64`.

Comment: @user3386109 I try your suggestion. Both Windows platform and macOS platform give identical result: `55 55 55 55 55 55 ffffffd5 3f`. It seems `printf` is the cause.

Answer (score 4):

According to the C standard, the following behaviour is [**implementation-defined**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.2p6):

> 6. The accuracy of the floating-point operations (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`) and of the library functions in `<math.h>` and `<complex.h>` that return floating-point results is implementation- defined, *as is the accuracy of the conversion between floating-point internal representations and string representations performed by the library functions in `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, and `<wchar.h>`. The implementation may state that the accuracy is unknown.*

Answer (score 2):

From the [MSVC docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hd7199ke(v=vs.120).aspx) since MSVC conform to IEEE **double** has up to **16** significant digits.

But [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb(v=vs.120).aspx) also state the by default the `/fp` flag is set to precise:

> With /fp:precise on x86 processors, the compiler performs rounding on
>   variables of type float to the correct precision for assignments and
>   casts and when parameters are passed to a function. This rounding
>   guarantees that the data does not retain any significance greater than
>   the capacity of its type.

So you're rounding of the double when passing it to `printf`, getting those zeros. As far as I can tell the trailing `1` is noise and should not be there (it's digit 17, I counted).

This behavior is `MSVC` specific, you can read more about it in the docs I linked to, to see what flags you would need for other compilers.

Comment: This does not explain the behaviour either.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Why? it's rounding the extra characters down - so 0. Did you try running with `/fp` set to something else before making that claim?

Comment: I'd also like to add that while "implementation defined" is correct, and also things may be OS/architecture/compiler dependent, it doesn't necessarily mean they wouldn't all give the same result. As evidence, try running this on a few machines, you'll see you do get the same results - of course, this is not guaranteed, merely luck (in the sense we're lucky the engineers/coders decided to implement similar behaviors).

Answer (score 1):

According to [coding-guidelines](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.3.1.5.html):

> **696** When a double is demoted to float, a long double is demoted to double or float, or a value being represented in greater precision and
>   range than required by its semantic type (see 6.3.1.8) is explicitly
>   converted to its semantic type (including to its own type), if the
>   value being converted can be represented exactly in the new type, it
>   is unchanged.
>
> **697** If the value being converted is in the range of values that can be represented but cannot be represented exactly, the result is
>   either the nearest higher or nearest lower representable value, chosen
>   in an implementation-defined manner.
>
> **698** If the value being converted is outside the range of values that can be represented, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: How does this answer the question? `0.33333333333333331482961625624739` is the nearest representable value exactly, `0.33333333333333331000000000` is that cut to 17 digits.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, different implementations may have `double` types with different characteristics, but that is not actually the cause of the behavior you are seeing here. In this case, the cause is that the Windows routines for converting floating-point values to decimal do not produce the correctly rounded result as defined in IEEE 754 (they “give up” after a limited number of digits), whereas the macOS routines do produce the correctly rounded result (and in fact produce the exact result if allowed to produce enough digits for that).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: yes, different platforms behave differently.

---

From [Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-xeon-processor-e5-2600-v2-product-family-technical-overview):

> Intel Xeon processor E5-2600 V2 product family supports half-precision (16-bit) floating- point data types. Half-precision floating-point data types provide 2x more compact data representation than single-precision (32-bit) floating-point data format, but sacrifice data range and accuracy. In particular, half-floats may provide better performance than 32-bit floats when the 32-bit float data does not fit into the L1 cache.

I don't have access to a Xeon machine to test this but I'd expect that you are ending up with a `double` that is not really a `double` due to the use of a "faster floating-point, but less precision" CPU instructions.

The "i" line of Intel Core processors doesn't have that half-width fast floating point precision so it doesn't truncate the result.

Here's more on the [half-precision format in Xeon](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/09/30/intel-half-precision-floating-point-format-conversion-instructions) on Intel website.